# Evaluating $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left({1\over1\cdot2\cdot3}+{1\over2\cdot3\cdot4}+\cdots+{1\over(n-1)\cdot n\cdot(n+1)}\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

The original question was to find $L=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^na_k$ where $a_n=\displaystyle{n\over(1+2+\cdots+(n-1))(1+2+\cdots+n)}$,

which I managed to get down to evaluating the following:

$$
L=4\lim_{n\to\infty} \left({1\over1\cdot2\cdot3}+{1\over2\cdot3\cdot4}+\cdots+{1\over(n-1)\cdot n\cdot(n+1)}\right)
$$

I've tried looking around the internet (as much as you can with these things), and the only thing I was able to find is  a method that uses definite integrals. I also found that the partial sum is $$\displaystyle {(n+2)(n+1)\over 4n(n+1)},$$ but this is definitely not something a student should have on the top of the head during the exam.

A hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Partial fraction decomposition. It telescopes.

Answer (score 6):

We first note that
$$
\frac{1}{(k-1)k(k+1)}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{k(k-1)}-\frac{1}{k(k+1)}\right),
$$
and thus
$$
4\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+2)}=2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{k(k+1)}-\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}\right)=\frac{2}{1\cdot 2}-\frac{2}{n(n+1)}.
$$
Consequently
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}4\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+2)}=1.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Expand by partial fractions:

$$\frac{1}{(n - 1)n(n + 1)} = -\frac 1 n + \frac 1 2 \frac 1 {n - 1} + \frac 1 2 \frac 1 {n + 1}$$

Now notice that a *lot* of the terms will cancel, and the series telescopes.

---

This is similar to, and motivated by the fact that

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {n(n + 1)} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac 1 n - \frac 1 {n + 1}$$

telescopes to leave $1$.

Comment: Is this an _extremly_ well known trick? I know the similar thing with $1/n(n+1)$, but I didn't know it could be done this way too. Is there a general formula for more than three factors?

Comment: Well, this case can be seen as $2$ terms, not three. $$\frac{1}{2n(n-1)} - \frac{1}{2n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{(n-1)n(n+1)}$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I like that perspective, makes it easier to derive instead of memorise! Thanks.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović The alternative way is to uses series, in particular the geometric series. You will have to integrate and multiply by $x$ several times and then finally plug in $x=1$ A lot of work but doable. In fact, had your series been alternating, I would go for series

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know how you should decompose a fraction, you can always use this method:

Let $$\frac{1}{(k-1)k(k+1)}=\frac{A}{k-1}+\frac{B}{k}+\frac{C}{k+1}$$

Then we have

$$1=Ak(k+1)+B(k-1)(k+1)+Ck(k-1)$$

$$\Leftrightarrow 1=Ak^2+Ak+Bk^2-B+Ck^2-Ck$$

$$\Leftrightarrow 1=(A+B+C)k^2+(A-C)k-B$$

Clearly, $A+B+C=0$, $A-C=0$ and $B=-1$

$\Rightarrow A=B=1/2$

Thus

$$\frac{1}{(k-1)k(k+1)}=\frac{1}{2(k-1)}-\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{2(k+1)}$$

Answer (score 1):

More generally, $$\frac{1}{n(n+1)\dots(n+k)} = \frac{1}k\left(\frac{1}{n(n+1)\dots(n+k-1)}-\frac{1}{(n+1)\dots(n+k)}\right)$$ so $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)\cdots (n+k)}$$ is a telescoping series with value $\frac{1}{k\cdot k!}$.

Comment: That lone exclamation mark looks like it means something exotic! A pity it's just a typo...

Comment: I think Tony means this one: http://i.imgur.com/tY246nh.png

Comment: Ah, when @TonyK said "lone," I didn't look further than the one I knew of, which I was afraid would be unclear. Fixed

Comment: @Steve: Thank you for preserving that for posterity! Now all we have to do is think up a meaning for it.